# Ruby on Rails 3: bundle install keeps failing with NoMethodErrors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

Whenever I try to make a new Rails project and run bundle install, I get errors like this:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs': undefined method `list' for #<Gem::SpecFetcher:0x8da5cc0> (NoMethodError)     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in     `block in remote_specs'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in     `each'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in     `remote_specs'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in     `fetch_specs'   from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in     `specs'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in     `block (2 levels) in index'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in     `each'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in     `block in index'    from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in     `build'    from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in     `index'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in     `resolve'   from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in     `specs'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in     `resolve_remotely!'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in     `run'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in     `install'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in     `install'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in     `run'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'   from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in     `dispatch'     from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'   from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in     `<top (required)>'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/bundle:23:in `load'  from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'    from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in     `eval'   from
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in     `<main>'
```

I already tried a lot, including completely uninstalling and purging rails, ruby and rvm from my system (even deleting leftover files and references to rvm in config files), but it always fails at this step. I tried bundler versions from 1.0.0 through 1.6.4, the latter one accidentally, Ruby 1.9.2, 1.9.3 and 2.1,  Rails 3.0.1, 3.0.2 and 3.2.6 The method it failes at varied somewhat through my different attempts, but the listed directory is always the same. .rvm is located in my home directory, which I omitted for privacy reasons.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0.2 with Ruby 1.9.3 (documentation was cheap.) on Bunsenlabs, a debian distribution. I issued the following commands to install ruby and rails and create my project:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --without-gems="rvm rubygems-bundler"
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm reload
rvm --default use 1.9.3
gem install rails --version 3.0.2
rails new railsapp3 -T
cd railsapp3
bundle install
```

( bundler ~>1.0.0 is the required version for rails 3.0.2)

This is the content of that project's gemfile:

> source 'http://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '3.0.2'
>
> gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'

This same method works without a hitch on my old laptop (same OS). I suspected it had something to do with version conflicts with different ruby installations, but I purged it thoroughly the last time I tried this.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how to resolve this!

**EDIT:**

For any poor soul who runs into this issue and stumbles upon this post, copypasting this gemfile (apparently for rails 3.1.0) sorta worked:

[ruby on rails 3 tutorial gemfile](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/rails-3-1/Gemfile)

Comment: Have you seen [this github issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2411)? Especially the steps including installing the old rake version in the comment by errakeshpd?

Comment: thank you for your answer! im pretty sure i already tried installing that version of rake, but it didnt seem to do anything. thats not to say there arent MORE issues that would obfuscate wether rake 0.8.7 was actually the issue. eventually i just copypasted another gemfile, which sorta worked ...